# DB2 window function - running total of X for preceding N minutes worth of rows

Tags: db2, window-functions

Very new to window functions but think I get the idea.

I'm trying to get a rolling sum of one column in 10 minute intervals (determined from a separate timestamp column)

A working sample might would look like this:

**EDIT:** [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=0804457530c69d31d4b3c5da10902e42)

[image]

Filtered for T2 highlights it better:

[image]

There's plenty about the topic like [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_olapspecification.html) or [this](https://jaxenter.com/10-sql-tricks-that-you-didnt-think-were-possible-125934.html) and [so on](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/181773/sum-of-previous-n-number-of-columns-based-on-some-category) but I'm having trouble finding a solution specific to my requirements.

If I didn't need it by 10 minute intervals it'd be very simple, by 10 rows (current + 9 preceding);

```
SELECT  ID, TIME, P/L,
    SUM(P/L) OVER (PARTITION BY ID
                     ORDER BY TIME
                     ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as ROLLING
FROM TABLE
```

Maybe adding the 10 min constraint is not possible with the window function?

**############## EDIT TWO ##############**

Ok, so I've figure out the issue and managed to reproduce it in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=a2c0e17e04b8465d6266c67830059101)

In the real table there are valid duplicate transactions (same ID and TIME), I thought I could pull back microseconds and solve this but unfortunately these aren't stored.

We end up with a weird backwards sum for the dupe's which may not be a huge issue but would rather fix if possible:

[image]

**########################################**

Comment: Maybe you need not `ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` but somethins like `RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 10 MINUTE PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`?

Comment: @Akina seems promising thanks, it's in some of the tutorials I'm looking at. DB2 doesn't seem to like it though

Comment: It seems DB2 do not support RANGE by value - only by count... [OLAP specification](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Db2 does not support the INTERVAL keyword on OLAP window-aggregation-group-clause  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html  so you need to convert the TIMESTAMPs to MINIUTEs first.  E.g

```
    ID
,   "TIME"
,   "P/L"
,   SUM("P/L") OVER (PARTITION BY ID
                 ORDER BY (DAYS("TIME") * 84000::BIGINT + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS("TIME"))/60
                 RANGE BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as ROLLING
FROM 
    TABLE(VALUES 
        ('T1','2020-01-07-15.10.00',1.2)
    ,   ('T1','2020-01-07-15.25.00',2.2)
    ,   ('T1','2020-01-07-15.30.00',3.2)
    ,   ('T1','2020-01-07-15.40.00',4.2)
    ) AS T(ID, "TIME", "P/L")
```

REturns

```
ID|TIME               |P/L|ROLLING
--|-------------------|---|-------
T1|2020-01-07-15.10.00|1.2|    1.2
T1|2020-01-07-15.25.00|2.2|    2.2
T1|2020-01-07-15.30.00|3.2|    5.4
T1|2020-01-07-15.40.00|4.2|    7.4
```

Comment: Looks like we're 95% there now, slight problem which can wait til I clock in tomorrow morning ;) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would use `RANGE`, not `ROWS`, after converting the timestamp to a numeric value:

```
SELECT  ID, tm, P/L,
    SUM(P/L) OVER (PARTITION BY ID
                     ORDER BY extract(epoch from tm)
                     range BETWEEN 600 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as ROLLING
FROM tbl
```

This [will work with Db2 for LUW 11.1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=bda28dc3008250a1604966c32571c65e) and later.

Comment: Thanks for posting, this works too. Same problem as mentioned under Paul Vernon's solution. Might be nothing/something I can sort myself tomorrow